# Random.nextBytes(byte[]) behavious in java

Tags: java, random

Question is, why is the behavior of acquiring the same number of bytes in separate method calls returns different bytes based on whether 5000 bytes where called in a single method call or 5000 method calls were made with a byte array of length 1.

Take the following example: Prints 21 in the terminal as opposed to 5000,(5000 divided by 256 gives ~19, which makes it likely that the 21 matches are simple coincidences).

```
Random rand = new Random(0);
byte tmp1[] = new byte[5000];
rand.nextBytes(tmp1);
rand = new Random(0);
byte tmp2[] = new byte[5000];
byte tmp3[] = new byte[1];
for(int i = 0; i < 5000;i++)
{
    rand.nextBytes(tmp3);
    tmp2[i] =tmp3[0];
}
int matches = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 5000;i++)
{
    if(tmp1[i] == tmp2[i])
    {
        matches++;
    }
}
System.out.println(matches);
```

More importantly, any way to hack it to have identical bytes generated irrelevant of whether I invoke the method with an array of length 5000 once or an array of length 2500 twice, etc.

Edit: The Post below answers the problem perfectly, Recieving bytes 4 at a time completely resolves the problem.
Test code is as follows, returns 4000:

```
                Random rand1 = new Random(0);
                byte tmp11[] = new byte[4000];
                rand1.nextBytes(tmp11);
                rand1 = new Random(0);
                byte tmp22[] = new byte[4000];
                byte tmp33[] = new byte[4];
                for(int i = 0; i < 1000;i++)
                {
                    rand1.nextBytes(tmp33);
                    for(int a = 0; a < 4;a++)
                    {
                        tmp22[(i*4)+a] = tmp33[a];
                    }
                }
                int matches1 = 0;
                for(int i = 0; i < 4000;i++)
                {
                    if(tmp11[i] == tmp22[i])
                    {
                        matches1++;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(matches1);
```

Comment: Is this where the random seed take place?

Comment: No, as can be seen in the example, both Random class instances have the seed 0. Seed is identical

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because java uses nextInt() to fill the bytes and add the other 3 of that int values bytes to the array. Basically each int received from the random generator fills 4 bytes of the array. I will add an example.

Here is the javadoc first:

> The method nextBytes is implemented by class Random as if by:
>
> ```
>  public void nextBytes(byte[] bytes) {    for (int i = 0; i <
>  bytes.length; )
>       for (int rnd = nextInt(), n = Math.min(bytes.length - i, 4);
>            n-- > 0; rnd >>= 8)
>        bytes[i++] = (byte)rnd; 
>  }
> ```

So now to show that example we can do:

```
      Random rand = new Random(0);
      rand.nextBytes(tmp1);
      System.out.println(tmp1[0]);
      System.out.println(tmp1[4]);
      rand = new Random(0);
      rand.nextBytes(tmp3);
      System.out.println(tmp3[0]);
      rand.nextBytes(tmp3);
      System.out.println(tmp3[0]);
```

Prints:
96
56
96
56 because the size of the int is 4. Basically it gets one int (which is 4 bytes) and adds it to the byte array in the positions 0,1,2,3. When you call it with byte[1] it gets the same int and adds the same byte to value 0 but the other 3 bytes from the int are lost. That's why you get inconsistency. The number 21 you get is just the coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

Since java's `Random` is a pseudorandom number generator, each time you call invoke any `next` method, its internal "state" will advance, i.e. a pseudorandom number possibly different from the previous one will be returned. In conjunction with the description of [`nextBytes`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextBytes-byte:A-) which states that it constructs the target bytes array from one call to `nextInt` for each 4 bytes in the target byte array, this leads to different results for your code.

Comment: There isn't a transformation. He just gets an int and loses the other 3 bytes from the int value. And when he has 5000 byte array he uses these 3 bytes. That's why the inconsistency

Comment: @VeselinDavidov dropping 3 bytes out of 4 is a transformation

Comment: yeah in a way ;) What I meant is that the pseudorandom number  generator will always give the same ints when fed with the same seed.  So he can rely on the random results to be the same every time - its just he is losing some bytes in the conversion.

Comment: In otherwords, requesting 1 byte, returns the first byte of the first nextInt() internal call, requesting one byte again, returns the first byte from the second internal nextInt() call, requesting two bytes returns the first and second byte from the third internal nextInt call

Comment: yeah if it gets 4 bytes anyway from nextInt()  it doesn't call random again but optimizes the call by using the other bytes